# Trouble inserting two array values into database

Tags: php, arrays

Here is the code I am using for multiple image upload for every entry in the database; id, image, name, date. By using this code, the image name is inserting correctly but I have a problem with the name field. I want to insert the name using `$product_name= $_POST['pro_name'];` but it only inserts 'array' in name field.

```
<?php
include('../config.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $product_name = $_POST['pro_name'];

    $j = 0;     // Variable for indexing uploaded image.
    $target_path = "uploads/";     // Declaring Path for uploaded images.
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']) && $product_name < count($product_name); $i++) {
        // Loop to get individual element from the array
        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");      // Extensions which are allowed.
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));   // Explode file name from dot(.)
        $file_extension = end($ext); // Store extensions in the variable.
        $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];     // Set the target path with a new name of image.
        $j = $j + 1;      // Increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array.
        if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000000)     // Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
                && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {

                $finel_name = explode('/', $target_path);
                $image_name_final = $finel_name[1];
                $jajsj = "insert into spec_product set image='$image_name_final', name='$product_name'";
                $janson = mysql_query($jajsj) or die(mysql_error());
                // If file moved to uploads folder.
                echo $j . ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
            } else {     //  If File Was Not Moved.
                echo $j . ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
            }
        } else {     //   If File Size And File Type Was Incorrect.
            echo $j . ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace in your code

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++)
    {
```

and add this before your query execute

```
$product_name_final= $product_name[$i];
```

Answer (score 1):

The value is inserting as array because the variable $product_name is not a string but an array. Whenever an array is used where a string was expected e.g.: concatenation of a string or in your case the query statment: insert into spec_product set image='$image_name_final', name='$product_name'"; PHP will automatically convert the array into its default string value "Array".

Make sure that $product_name is not an array but a string which contains name of the product you want to insert in the table.

Regards,
Nitin Thakur

Comment: thanks nitin but i am also using for
** 
($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']) && $product_name < count($product_name); $i++) ** in for loop to count the array where i am wrong